# Is there a way to model replies in a feed of communication?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with the following columns:

`communication_id`|`communication_date`|`company_id`|`customer_id`|`salesperson_id`|`medium`|`is_incoming`|`is_outgoing`|`communication_text`

Where `communication_id` is the grain of the table, and `medium` can be values like `phone`, `sms` etc. `is_incoming` and `is_outgoing` are indicator columns for the direction of the communication, in the perspective of the salesperson. If a salesperson sends the communication, we'd have a 0 for `is_incoming` and a 1 for `is_outgoing`.

So, given a `customer_id` ordered by `communication_date`, I have the feed of communication between that customer and their salesperson. If I see that the salesperson had 2 incoming communications, and then had 1 outgoing communication to that customer, then our rule/inference is to label that outgoing communication as a reply, and so on and so forth. By this logic, only `is_outgoing` communications can be replies. So, I think what I need to do is build an `is_salesperson_reply` column that indicates whether the communication was a reply. I think what would also be helpful would be to also surface the `communication_id` of the communication they are replying to as `salesperson_replied_to_communication_id` and the timestamp of that as `salesperson_replied_to_at`.

What I'm trying to write is a select query that outputs a summary of salesperson communication; I'm already able to create a table where I have each salesperson and the total number of communications, total sent, and total received. I'd now like to model the number of replies they made and perhaps the average amount of time it takes for them to reply, when they do.

I have a feeling that I may need to use the `array_agg` function or some fancy `case` statements, but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So, when you say that you're trying to, "output a summary..."  What you're asking for is a SELECT query that returns that data?

Comment: @DeadZone That's right -- sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Can you be more specific about your version of SQL?  Knowing if this is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 vs. MySQL vs. etc. can help establish what instance-specific syntax is allowed.

Comment: So total number of communications, total sent and total received can all be done with `Group By` and aggregate functions.  It's the average response time that's going to require a little more work.  But I think this should be reasonable doable using the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Here is some [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a1347f/5) to get you started.

Comment: hey @DeadZone, i'm using Snowflake. Is that enough information on the version of SQL? And right on, total comms + total sent + total received are all done with `sum` and `group by` statements, which I've already achieved. modeling replies tricky and what i'm stuck on, but once I model that I can find the average response time by using a `datediff` to find the the delta, and then averaging them.

Comment: I checked out the SQLFiddle and was able to implement it -- I also added a `partition by customer_id` clause so the `datediff` is performed with respect to the customer. However, this doesn't solve the problem of categorizing certain messages as replies -- this simply finds the difference in seconds between the current and previous message, which isn't necessarily the response time.

Comment: It's a bit unclear from your description... is any outgoing communication a reply?  Or is it only an outgoing communication that has an incoming communication immediately preceding it?

Comment: I was able to resolve this from your suggestion on using the lag function -- thanks for that! Apologies if my descriptions were unclear

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fiddle provided by @Deadzone, this can be achieved with:

```sql
USE "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC";
INSERT INTO Communications VALUES (101, '5/1/2019 13:00:00', 12345, 0, 'First Incoming Communication'),
 (102, '5/1/2019 13:00:10', 12345, 1, 'First Outgoing Communication'),
 (103, '5/1/2019 13:00:14', 12345, 0, 'Second Incoming Communication'),
 (111, '5/1/2019 13:01:00', 12345, 1, 'Second Outgoing Communication'),
 (121, '5/1/2019 13:02:00', 12345, 1, 'Third Outgoing Communication'),
 (122, '5/1/2019 13:02:08', 12345, 0, 'Third Incoming Communication')

SELECT *, 
  DATEDIFF(second, 
           LAG(communication_date, 1, communication_date) OVER (ORDER BY communication_date),
           communication_date) AS ResponseTimeInSeconds
FROM Communications C
WHERE Customer_id = 12345
ORDER BY communication_date;
```

```sql
## COMMUNICATION_ID COMMUNICATION_DATE  CUSTOMER_ID IS_OUTGOING COMMUNICATION_TEXT  RESPONSETIMEINSECONDS
## 101  2019-05-01 13:00:00.000 12345   0   First Incoming Communication    0
## 102  2019-05-01 13:00:10.000 12345   1   First Outgoing Communication    10
## 103  2019-05-01 13:00:14.000 12345   0   Second Incoming Communication   4
## 111  2019-05-01 13:01:00.000 12345   1   Second Outgoing Communication   46
## 121  2019-05-01 13:02:00.000 12345   1   Third Outgoing Communication    60
## 122  2019-05-01 13:02:08.000 12345   0   Third Incoming Communication    8
```